# Creating non reoccuring random groups of people

Tags: math, random, grouping

So this isn't really an informatics question but I'm guessing the solution lies in informatics.

We have a group of 100 students that are meant to have discussion amongst each other. For this we want to separate them into 10 groups of 10 people.
We want to have three rounds of discussions, however we want the groups to be different each time. No one person should get to sit with the same person twice.

Say we assign our groups letters
abcdefghij (10)
Person1 gets Round1:A Round2:B Round3:C
Person2 gets Round1:A but then can't have Round2:B or Round3:C because they would then meet again.

Doing this by hand sounds pretty insane and I'm sure there is a pretty simple solution for this. Maybe even a program that does exactly this, but I just can't find it or don't know what to search for...

Sadly I have no skills whatsoever in programming, but maybe this can even be done in excel or sth like that?

All help or tips apreciated.
Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I'm sure people over at http://math.stackexchange.com/ would answer this question in no time, considering this question does not appear to be looking for a programming answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best suited for `math.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done in the excel. You just need the 3 step approach:

1. Mix the students in the random fashion.
2. Create one set of mixes which don't repeat the students
3. Apply the transformation of the order to the students

The tricky one is 2nd.

The exemplary mix is:

Since the order of the students is random, you can divide them in the 10 groups of ten people, that is easy. So we have the 1st discussion done.

For second discussion you can take the 1st person of each group (take every 10th person) as they were not in the same groups at the 1st time.

Then take the 1st person from 1st group, 2nd from the 2nd, 3rd from the 3rd. In this way you can clearly see that no person is with the same person in the group. For the rest of groups just go with different starts so 1st person from 2nd group goes with the 2nd person to 3rd group etc.

Even though this is not the only solution it is reasonably easy to implement. Even doable in excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need three rounds, you can probably get by with a "difference scheme", or even a random process coupled with rejection of unsuitable arrangements. However, if you can change the number 100 a little bit, you can get some more interesting results.

For example, it is easy to construct so-called "resolvable balanced incomplete block designs" on a set of 81 elements, 9 groups, no pair appears more than once in a group. You can do that with the `sage` system command `echo 'print(designs.AffineGeometryDesign(2,1,9))' | sage > output.txt`. Unfortunately, sage prints the blocks in lexicographic order, but you can easily rearrange them in a more useful order. Similarly `print(designs.AffineGeometryDesign(2,1,11))` provides a block design with 121 elements in groups of 11. Using 10 instead of 9 or 11 doesn't work out: the number must be a power of a prime.

The output of those commands is rather long, so I'll do a simpler example, with 4 instead of 9. The output is

```
AffineGeometryDesign<points=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
blocks=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 4, 8, 12], [0, 5, 10, 15], [0, 6, 11, 13], [0, 7, 9, 14], 
[1, 4, 11, 14], [1, 5, 9, 13], [1, 6, 8, 15], [1, 7, 10, 12], [2, 4, 9, 15], 
[2, 5, 11, 12], [2, 6, 10, 14], [2, 7, 8, 13], [3, 4, 10, 13], [3, 5, 8, 14], 
[3, 6, 9, 12], [3, 7, 11, 15], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]>
```

`points` just gives the numbering of the points; note that it starts at 0 instead of 1, and that there are 16 points altogether. More interesting is `blocks`. We can rearrange the blocks as follows:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15]
[0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 4, 11, 14], [2, 7, 8, 13], [3, 6, 9, 12] 
[0, 6, 11, 13], [1, 7, 10, 12], [2, 4, 9, 15], [3, 5, 8, 14]
[0, 7, 9, 14], [1, 6, 8, 15], [2, 5, 11, 12], [3, 4, 10, 13]
```

Each row covers the ground set with 4 disjoint subsets. Pick any pair of numbers and you'll find that they are in one and only one block together. This allows you to extend beyond three rounds in cases where an rBIBD exists.

One way to deal with 100 students would be to add 21 "fake" students (which could just be empty placeholders or could be teachers, teaching assistants, research assistants, etc.) and use the (121,11,1)-rBIBD generated by Sage.